# Integrate DocuSign using RestAPI

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to implement the [DocuSign embedded signing](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning). I'm kind of successful with few things left.

Without a developer account it's not possible to use the API, isn't it? I both have a pro account and a free account. Then I created a developer account with the same email and password I have for the free account. But when signing a document it says:

> Demonstration Document Only.

Please see the image for better understanding:

[image]

Why is this appearing? Is it because I am using a developer account that has the same credentials as the free account? Will it disappear if I create a developer account with the same email and password I have for the pro account?

If I want to work with the API then will I have to control everything from developer account? I mean add template and other relevant signing stuff. Then what's the pro account for, which I've purchased?

Also, recipient is not receiving any email. Please see the images for better understanding:

[image]

[image]

I've asked the same thing at DocuSign support, but left with no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DocuSign - API Certification Process](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/certification)

Integrations using DocuSign APIs must go through the Certification process to operate in the DocuSign production environment. During API Certification, the Integration is examined for following DocuSign’s Security & Design Requirements. We recommend reviewing our API Requirements Guide prior to beginning development as it will streamline the certification process later.

In order to avoid delays in processing please make sure the following items have been satisfied prior to beginning the process. These are explained in further detail in the API Certification Guide.

- 1) Customer or Partner sales contract has been executed.
- 2) 20+ test
  transactions have already been executed.

Please review the following guides prior to beginning the API Certification process, a sample list of questions that will be asked has also been provided:

[API PDF Security & Design Requirements](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/api-requirements-w-connect-guides.pdf) | [API PDF API Certification InfoSheet](https://a68a3b79fef41dab4513-f03eeda740093cbe74371aff89dec8d1.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/API_Certification_InfoSheet_4_9_15.pdf)

Please e-mail any questions regarding the API Certification process to apicertifications@docusign.com or your DocuSign Account Manager.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Wilson. I can't understand what to do.I do have a production account.I filled up the document which appears on clicking on the "START API CERTIFICATION" button in the DocuSign - API Certification Process page. I don't know for sure what happened. I was not notified anything when signing was finished. How long does api integration process take?  Will it cost me anymore money? Please help me once again. I'm still finding no way out.

Comment: Your account manager is the correct person to ask all of those questions to.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Wilson. I wonder how I can get hold of my account manager. Would you please help me out? I've left a email in this address apicertifications@docusign.com  But still no response.

Comment: You can contact DocuSign Customer Support to be transferred to your Account Manager. or apicertifications will get back to you, I'm just not sure how long that may take. They may have a large email queue